# Protractor load testing browser tab not working properly

Tags: protractor

I am trying to do load testing but facing some issues. Scenario below

- open webapp localhost:2244
- click drop down
- Select a profile from drop down.
- on click on profile aggrid is populated from server

In the code i have following

```
browser.get(url)
element(by(<drop down>)).click()
element(by(<profile>)).click()
browser.driver.sleep(4000) //wait for aggrid to populate from server
```

The problem i am facing are

- when i open url only once it works fine but when i open the same url multple times in a loop it doesn't open in different tab and the same tab gets updated. i tried to open in multiple tabs but only one tab opens properly and other remains empty.
- How can i concurrently open 1000s or url as if many different users are opening the url and keep track of each page seperately and verify aggrid.

Comment: Why do you want to load test using protractor? why don;t you use load testing tools?

Comment: Can you please share some load testing tool for angular project

Comment: You can use LoadRunner